# Get Multiple Select Query Value as a Table

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am using a stored procedure in which I am using multiple select statements, but these statements are returning the values as multiple result sets, but I want the return value in a single result set.

Here is my procedure:

```
Create Proc GetRequestDetail
As
Begin
    Select Count(ReceiverId) As GetInvitation 
    From Requests 
    Where ReceiverId = 1044 

    Select Count(SenderId) As GetSendInvitation 
    From Requests 
    Where SenderId = 10

    Select Count(ID) As GetAcceptedRequest 
    From Requests 
    Where ReceiverId = 7 And Status = 2735

    Select Count(ID) As GetRejectedRequest 
    From Requests 
    Where ReceiverId = 2182 And Status = 2736

    Select Count(ID) As GetAcceptRequest 
    From Requests 
    Where SenderId = 10 And status = 1255

    Select Count(ID) As GetrejectRequest 
    From Requests 
    Where SenderId = 10 And status = 1256
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all results need to be in the same row:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRequestDetail
as
begin

    SELECT
        GetInvitation = (Select Count(ReceiverId)  from Requests Where ReceiverId = 1044 ),
        GetSendInvitation = (Select Count(SenderId)  from Requests Where SenderId = 10),
        GetAcceptedRequest = (Select Count(ID)  from Requests where ReceiverId = 7 and Status = 2735),
        GetRejectedRequest = (Select Count(ID) as GetRejectedRequest from Requests where ReceiverId = 2182 and Status = 2736),
        GetAcceptRequest = (Select Count(ID) as GetAcceptRequest from Requests where SenderId = 10 and status = 1255),
        GetrejectRequest = (Select Count(ID) as GetrejectRequest from Requests where SenderId = 10 and status = 1256)

end
```

On a side note, it seems that you are missing paramters to your SP (maybe receiving the searched IDs as parameters?). Could be something like the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetRequestDetail
    @ReceivedID INT,
    @SenderID INT
as
begin

    SELECT
        GetInvitation = (Select Count(ReceiverId)  from Requests Where ReceiverId = @ReceivedID ),
        GetSendInvitation = (Select Count(SenderId)  from Requests Where SenderId = @SenderID),
        GetAcceptedRequest = (Select Count(ID)  from Requests where ReceiverId = @ReceivedID and Status = 2735),
        GetRejectedRequest = (Select Count(ID) as GetRejectedRequest from Requests where ReceiverId = @ReceivedID and Status = 2736),
        GetAcceptRequest = (Select Count(ID) as GetAcceptRequest from Requests where SenderId = @SenderID and status = 1255),
        GetrejectRequest = (Select Count(ID) as GetrejectRequest from Requests where SenderId = @SenderID and status = 1256)

end
```